# How do I improve my weapon in Gears of war 3 multiplayer

Tags: gears-of-war-3

I am new to multiplayer mode in GOW3 .
I am limited to a choice of two simple weapons.
I have noticed I have to shoot a lot in order to injure an opponent but a lot of them can take  me down with a single shot.

Can I keep weapons that I pick up in multiplayer games for later matches?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This game is not like CoD in that you are always limited to the first five starting weapons (Lancer, Retro Lancer, Sawed-Off, Gnasher, Hammerburst). From the multiplayer options menu, you can rotate your primary and secondary weapons between these. However, you will never be able to start with weapons other than these.

During multiplayer matches, one useful strategy is to learn where better weapons are in each map and try to get them (e.g., if you like using the Longshot, know where it is on each map).

You also mentioned that you have to shoot a lot to kill but go down easily. This may be due to a few factors. One is that they may have better accuracy then you and are getting headshots. This game has been out since September, so don't be suprised that people are ridiculously accurate. Another issue is the perfect active reload. Your opponents may be emptying clips at the beginning of the match to get to perfect active reload for quicker kills. To perfect active reload, while reloading, press the right bumper button while the moving line is within the white line. This will have varying affects on your weapons (e.i., some will gain damage, lose spread, or increase fire rate). This is a necessary skill in order to survive in multiplayer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint - The X Button is the use / interact button for picking up weapons/ammo, Screen shot below:)
[image: Hold X to pick up and switch weapons]

Heres a list of all the changes in the Gears of War 3 weapons since beta:

Heres a list of ALL the weapons on Gears of War 3:
http://www.ign.com/wikis/gears-of-war-3/Weapons

Heres the controls for Gears of War 3 for XBOX Live; it shows the button to switch weapons and pick up weapons :)
http://gearsofwar.wikia.com/wiki/Controls

To change starting weapons, Watch this video which shows step by step how to customize both starting weapons and skins:

Comment: Yes - but when I pick it up - it is there only for the current game. next round I will stil be with a regular weak weapon. I want it to be constant. that was my original question

Comment: Watch this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Yyf3d4MVPM